# How do I determine passive insight/perception?

Tags: dnd-4e, character-creation

I just don't know how to find what I'm supposed to put in for insight and perception. How are they calculated?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Passive [any skill]** is the same as when **Taking 10**. So that's 10 + your **base skill bonus**.

This is covered in the *Player's Handbook* in chapter 5: "Skills", in the "Checks without Rolls" section on page 179.

Comment: thx you helped quick and base skill bonus? im new player

Comment: @rader I suggest asking your DM or reading the PHB/utilizing the D&D Insider Compendium.